# Gmail's Support of Media Queries Limited by Location?

Tags: css, email, gmail, html-email, mpmediaquery

Now that Gmail supports media queries (https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/css) does any know of limitations such as location (i.e., only available for US based email addresses) or if the update is limited to just webmail?

Email on acid did a webinar about the updates and didn't say any of the above limitations existed - but the company I use to build and deploy emails, is saying media query support is not available in Canada.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, they are rolling it out based on geo location and product.**

As of October 2016, U.S.-based Gmail accounts are starting to see media query support whereas U.K.-based accounts are not. Litmus Previews use UK Gmail accounts, so we won't see the update appear in Litmus regardless of where we're testing from.

Gmail is also rolling out based on Gmail product. Here is a quick breakdown of where the rollout stands now:
[image]

[More info and updated charts on Litmus](https://litmus.com/blog/gmail-to-support-responsive-email-design)

Answer (score 0):

Given that there is an explicit [list of supported properties and media queries](https://developers.google.com/gmail/design/reference/supported_css) and said list does not mention any such location dependencies, the official answer to your question is that there are no such limitations.

From the reference:

> Supported types
>
> - all
> - screen
>
> Supported queries
>
> - min-width
> - max-width
> - min-device-width
> - max-device-width
> - orientation
> - min-resolution
> - max-resolution
>
> Supported keywords
>
> - and
> - only

Comment: Thank you. I was under the same impression. 

Appreciate your input!

Comment: DO note that the roll-out is limited to @gmail.com addresses. If you're using the Gmail app to read email to a non-gmail account (GANGA as they call it) the style block will still be stripped.